# ORA-00904: "DWH_ITEM_SEQ"."NEXTAVL": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

Can anyone explain to me why I get a 00904 error when I run the following
I need to insert into tabel a 100 rows and I dont no why the error

```
 drop table DWH_ITEM_DIM;
 CREATE TABLE DWH_ITEM_DIM(
 ITEM_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
 ITEM_NAME VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
 ITEM_TYPE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
 ITEM_COST NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
 ITEM_PRICE NUMBER(10,2) NOT NULL,
 ITEM_FOR_SALE VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT ITEM_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_ID));

  DROP SEQUENCE DWH_ITE_SEQ;
 CREATE SEQUENCE DWH_ITE_SEQ
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

 TRUNCATE TABLE DWH_ITEM_DIM;
 INSERT INTO DWH_ITEM_DIM
 SELECT DWH_ITE_SEQ.NEXTAVL AS ITEM_ID,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',5) AS ITEM_NAME,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',1) AS ITEM_TYPE,
 ROUND(dbms_random.value(LOW =>25,HIGH =>300),2) AS ITEM_COST,
 ROUND(dbms_random.value(LOW =>25,HIGH =>300),2) AS ITEM_PRICE,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',1) AS ITEM_FOR_SALE
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100;
 COMMIT;
```

When I run this the 'script Output' is:

```
table DWH_ITEM_DIM dropped.
table DWH_ITEM_DIM created.
sequence DWH_ITE_SEQ dropped.
sequence DWH_ITE_SEQ created.
table DM.DWH_ITEM_DIM truncated.

Error starting at line 19 in command:
INSERT INTO DM.DWH_ITEM_DIM
 SELECT DWH_ITE_SEQ.NEXTAVL AS ITEM_ID,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',5) AS ITEM_NAME,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',1) AS ITEM_TYPE,
 ROUND(dbms_random.value(LOW =>25,HIGH =>300),2) AS ITEM_COST,
 ROUND(dbms_random.value(LOW =>25,HIGH =>300),2) AS ITEM_PRICE,
 DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('U',1) AS ITEM_FOR_SALE
 FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
Error at Command Line:20 Column:8
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DWH_ITE_SEQ"."NEXTAVL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
commited.
```

I don't no why? please help me I'm new in oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo, change `NEXTAVL` TO `NEXTVAL`.

Answer (score 3):

Try `NEXTVAL` instead of `NEXTAVL`.